# Dynamic validations for programmatically rendered Redux Fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

Wasn't able to find a direct answer to an issue I'm having, so hoping someone on SO can help me out...

I have a simple Redux form which has only a `First Name` and `Last Name` input field. Rather than being written out explicitly, these fields are rendered programmatically, like so:

```js
...

renderNameInput(field) {
  const { content } = this.props;

  return (
    <Field
      id={field}
      name={field}
      component={FormField}
      validate={this.nameValidations}
      error={!this.isNameValid(field) ? content.nameError : null}
    />
  );
}

...

render() {
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <div>
      {this.renderNameInput('firstName')}
      {this.renderNameInput('lastName')}
    </div>
  </form>
}
```

The issue I am having is showing an error when a field does not validate. Each field requires a minimum of 2 characters, and a maximum of 16 (*though this is no relevant to my specific question*).

What I am trying to do, is that when one of the inputs is not valid, the error is displayed under that input. If both inputs are not valid, then the error will show under both inputs (*the structure and styling for showing the errors in their respective locations is of course done, just not part of this question*)

Here is the method I have that is checking for the errors:

```js
...

isNameValid(field) {
  const { formState = {} } = this.props;
  const { syncErrors } = formState;

  if (syncErrors && syncErrors[field]) {
    return false;
  }
}

...
```

The component is connected to the Redux store, so I have access to the `formState` and the `initial` and `values` objects in the form, as well as when they have been `visit`ed, `touch`ed, etc.

If - when an input value is changed by the user - the `syncErrors` object were to look like this when looking at the Redux state in the store (*arbitrarily*):

```
syncErrors: {
  firstName: 'Must be at least 2 characters'
}
```

Then I would like an error message to show under the `firstName` input, but nothing under the `lastName` input. Likewise, should `lastName` be part of the `syncErrors` object, then the error would show under that input as well. If both `firstName` and `lastName` are in `syncErrors`, then the error would show under both inputs.

I hope this made sense, and someone can point me in the right direction. If any clarification is needed, please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually was able to get this figured out. I made this method:

```js
...

isNameError(field) {
  const { content, formState = {}, submitFailed } = this.props;
  const { initial, syncErrors, values } = formState;

  if (!submitFailed || !syncErrors) {
    return null;
  }

  const isNotSameValues = initial[field] !== values[field];
  const invalidField = Boolean(isNotSameValues && syncErrors[field]);

  if (invalidField) {
    return content.nameError;
  }
}

...
```

Since this component was wrapped with `reduxForm`, I was able to use certain props passed down to my wrapped component - `submitFailed` and `syncErrors`. If the form field did not pass my validation check, the `syncErrors` object would be populated with the form field name as the key, and the validation error (*the error message*) as the value.

Also when the form failed being submitted due to failed validation, the `submitFailed` prop - a boolean - was set to `true`.

I connected my component to the Redux store, so I was able to access the `formState`, and use the `initial` and `values` props to compare each input field value and run a validation check.

Utilizing this in my initial `renderNameInput` method looks like so:

```js
...

renderNameInput(field) {
  const { content, formState = {}, submitFailed } = this.props;

  const label = get(content, `${field}Field.text`, '');

  return (
    <Field
      id={field}
      name={field}
      component={FormField}
      validate={this.nameValidations}
      error={isNameError(field)}
    />
  );
}

...
```

Each input field gets validated individually, and if it does not pass the checks on the intial submit, then the error message is shown under each input. When that input passes the check, the error goes away, and I can submit.

Thanks alot for your help though, @ldtcoop!

Answer (score 0):

<strike>If you are passing in the error message as a prop to the `Field` component, then you will probably just want to add some code to the `Field` component that shows an error if there is one. It should look something like this:
`{this.props.error ? (<p>{this.props.error}</p>) : null}`</strike>

Since you can't change what appears in the `Field` component, I would suggest allowing the component in which `renderNameInput` exists to access the error object in Redux. That way you could make `renderNameInput` return the `Field` component and the error message. Something like this:

```
renderNameInput(field) {
  const { content, error } = this.props;

  return (
    <div>
      <Field
        id={field}
        name={field}
        component={FormField}
        validate={this.nameValidations}
        error={!this.isNameValid(field) ? content.nameError : null}
      />
      <p>{error[field] ? (<p>{error[field]}</p>) : null}}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yea, that would normally be exactly what I would do. Unfortunately, the `FormField` component that I am wrapping with Redux `Field` is coming from a UI Kit that is an npm package, which another team works on, and cannot be edited by me. The `error` prop is supposed to just show the error if there is one, or show nothing. I am trying to show the error for the correct input, without showing it for both inputs even if only 1 fails the validation...

Comment: @Lushmoney, please see my new edit and see if that solves your problem satisfactorily